# Automate download of Drupal webform data

Tags: csv, export, drupal-6, drupal-webform

I'm working on integrating my data between two different database systems - our site itself is run on Drupal 6.2.8, but our customer database is run by a third-party on a different system. It is capable of importing data from a csv.

I'm capturing data with a Drupal webform - that's working great. I know that I can manually download a csv from the webform - but I want to run imports frequently - at least daily. I found this thread: http://drupal.org/node/1276098 that talks about a drush command for exporting webforms, but it doesn't seem to be complete.

I know that I can use views to create a csv, but I don't seem to have access to the submissions themselves from views. Likewise I know that the data module can somehow be tied into the answer for this, but I am not at all sure how to get started with it.

If there were just a simple way to schedule downloads of the data, I could set up an rsync or something like that to handle the rest - any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The following code may work for the case:

```
drush webform-export <Specify-WebFormID>  --completion-type=finished --delimiter="|" --file=<Specify-Filename> --format=delimited
```

You may also use --range-start and --range-type options to be more precise in which result you'd like to get.